# How do I store a unique record of a jQuery object in a database for later retrieval and interaction?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a two-way communication system where there is a viewer+presenter mode on a website.

When a presenter clicks on an object on the page, the viewer should see that click.

**Short Description of What I Want To Achieve**

The problem I am facing is how to save and identify the actual object between the otherwise isolated viewports. Storing/Getting from the db is easy, but how do I 'link' the two objects in the Presenter vs. Viewer mode?

**More detail:**

My prototype uses websockets to communicate between the two, and it works. But now I need to change to to a DB backend for reasons.

How can my Presenter pack or identify the jQuery object that is clicked and save it in the database. Then, also retrieve that info, and act on that object in the Viewer to force the click to happen?

The process would be simple:

1. handle a click event and push it to db through ajax:

```html
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: url + '/api/v1/events/presenter/store',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        'api_key': window.dataLayer.app.api_key,
        'presentation_id': window.dataLayer.app.presentation_id,
        'event': that.data.last_event
    }
})
```

2. In the viewer, a polling process is running and looks for recent events:

```html
poller: function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: url + '/api/v1/events/viewer/get',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'client_id': window.dataLayer.app.client_id,
            'api_key': window.dataLayer.app.api_key,
            'presentation_id': window.dataLayer.app.presentation_id,
        }
    }).done(function(r) {
    }).fail(function(r) {
        console.error(r);
    });
},
```

I did try and convert the jQuery object to JSON a variety of ways, including `JSON.stringify($(object))` to no avail.

I'm missing any GUID or unique identifier on the object itself, unless of course I manually add an ID, which I can't necessarily rely on if I port this process to a different site. Plus that sounds like overkill to have to manually assign ids to *every* clickable object.

One idea that I did think of is to programmatically add an incremental id to each object in the DOM, that way each side viewer and presenter would get the same ids, because they would be created in the same order.

Something like this:

```html
(function() {
    var guid = 0;
    $.fn.guid = function() {
         var node = this[0];
         if (node.guid === undefined) {
              node.guid = guid++;
         }
         return node.guid;
    };
}());
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't provide any code or show how you've attempted to solve this already

Comment: Ok, good call. I will add more details.

Comment: yeah, the problem is how to save and identify the object between the otherwise isolated viewports. otherwise the db storing part is finished.

Comment: check out my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

No, the object would no longer represent the actual DOM element on the page. The way jQuery works, it has to query for the dom element on the page after the entire DOM has been generated. That's why you wait for "document ready" and why dynamically added elements have to be queried for again, or listeners have to be on parent DOM elements and listen for events to bubble up.

It's best to just select that object again using a unique ID.

If you think it's overkill, look at the IDs created by any ASP.net page. Each object has an ID based on its parent DOM elements with an auto-incremented id number at the end, all separated by underscores.

---

If you're saving these into a database, by necessity those things will have a primary key to make them unique. When rendering the objects to the page, simply add a `data-id` attribute, and you can select by that data attribute, eg:

`$("div[data-id='ITEM_PRIMARY_KEY']").trigger("click");`

Replacing `ITEM_PRIMARY_KEY` with the primary key, and `div` with the type of tag (might be an anchor tag, or whatever, not sure your setup).

Comment: Your last paragraph is a nasty anti-pattern devised by Microsoft due to a misunderstanding of how IDs/DOM selectors work.  Thankfully we've moved on a bit from those days.

Comment: I wasn't defending the practice, just calling attention to its wide use in the wild. ASP.net also abused the form element in order to make dynamic/server side pages possible. It was a novel idea developed way before Node or Angular were invented. Antiquated now, yes.

Comment: This is kinda in line with the approach I was considering- attaching an identifier on page load, that just happens to match up on each side. So basically in your example, I could loop through all the valid objects in the DOM and add a data-primary-key to them.